Importing jQuery and Bootstrap in a JS file
I'm having problems with importing libraries in my JS file.
My code is correct as it works if i use it in the script tag in my html file (where i imported jQuery and Bootstrap). However if the same code is in my JS file, it doesn't work.
I tried to import the Bootstrap library with the link in this way but it doesn't work:
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";

Then I tried to copy the whole library on a new js file created by me and import it but it still doesn't work.
import "bootstrap-copy.js";


To import jQuery and Bootstrap into a JavaScript file, you can follow these steps:
Install via npm: If you're using npm, install both libraries with npm install jquery bootstrap.
Import in your JS file:
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';

Alternatively, include them in your HTML file:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


Sorry i don't really know how to use npm. Is there another way?

Looks like AI generated answer.
